# MATLAB: symbolic integral of symfun

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, integral

I wish to perform a symbolic integration over time; the code is given below.

```
syms x1 u1 t
x1 = symfun(sym('x1(t)'), [t]);
x1dot = p1 + p4*p8 - p13*x1;
int(x1dot,t)
```

The answer should be:

```
e^(-p13*t)*x1(0)+(p1 + p4*p8)/(-p13)*[1-e^(-p13*t)]
```

what I get is:

```
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found. 

ans(t) =

int(p1 - p13*x1(t) + p4*p8*u1(t), t)
```

It seems to me that it does not recognize that `x1dot` is the derivative of `x1`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What are `p1`, `p4`, `p8`, and `p13`? Edit your question and define these. from your error, it looks like `u1` is also a `symfun`. Show your actuall code and actual full error message. Also Your first two lines of code can be written simply as `syms x1(t) u1` (there's no reason to call `symfun` explicitly).

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not strictly speaking integration, i.e. from a known function `f(t)` deduce a function `F(t)` such that the derivative of `F` is `f`. The original function is not really known, since it depends on itself (no matter how trivial the relationship might seem to a human, you need to inverse it).

It is rather solving a differential equation, [for which `dsolve` is probably the way to go](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dsolve.html). MATLAB has no way to guess that `x1dot` is the derivative of `x1`. I guess you could declare `x1dot=diff(x1)` but why not use `diff(x1)` directly where needed ?

Comment: Yes. I'll that the issue is that `x(t)`, for example, is what Matlab refers to as an arbitrary or abstract symbolic function (one without a specific definition). For the reasons stated above, even something as simple as `int(x(t),t)` cannot be "solved", but must be left in integral form. Matlab cannot guess how `x(t)` depends on `t`.